# Проверка результата игры

Tags: разработка-игр, c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int II()
{
    int i = 0, summ = 0, d = 1;
    while (d == 1) {
        i = rand() % 10 + 2;
        while (i == 5)
            i = rand() % 10 + 2;
        summ += i;
        if (summ > 22)
            break;
        if (summ == 21)
            break;
        if ((summ < 12) || (summ == 15) || (summ == 18))
            d = 1;
        if ((summ == 20) || (summ == 19) || (summ == 17)
            || (summ == 14))
            d = 0;
    }
    return summ;
}

int proverit(int user, int bot)
{               
    /* проблема вот с этой функцией, никак не могу заставить ее нормально работать */
    if ((user == 21) & (bot < 21)) {
        cout << "Пользователь выйграл" << endl;
    }
    if ((user < 21) & (bot < 21) & (user > bot)) {
        cout << "Пользователь выйграл" << endl;
    }
    if ((user < 21) & (bot > 21)) {
        cout << "Пользователь выйграл" << endl;
    }
    if ((user < 21) & (bot < 21) & (user > bot)) {
        cout << "Пользователь выйграл" << endl;
    }

    if ((user > 21) & (bot == 21)) {
        cout << "Бот выйграл" << endl;
    }
    if ((user < 21) & (bot < 21) & (user < bot)) {
        cout << "Бот выйграл" << endl;
    }
    if ((user > 21) & (bot < 21)) {
        cout << "Бот выйграл" << endl;
    }

    if ((user == bot)) {
        cout << "Ничья" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");   //вывод кириллицы
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0, summ = 0, d = 1;
    while (d == 1) {
        system("cls");
        i = rand() % 10 + 2;
        while (i == 5)
            i = rand() % 10 + 2;
        summ += i;
        cout << "Сумма карт на данный момент:" <<
            summ << endl;
        if (summ >= 22)
            break;
        if (summ == 21)
            break;
        cout << "Нужно еще? Да(1), Нет(0)" << endl;
        cin >> d;
    }
    system("cls");
    proverit(summ, II());
    cout << "_________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "Ваш результат:" << summ << endl;
    cout << "Результат ИИ:" << II() << endl;
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Вопрос требует уточнения: что, зачем и как делается.

Comment: @insolor, я восхищен !

Comment: @avp, все гениальное просто) Правда мне почему-то кажется что в данном случае это особой роли не играет.

Еще не понятно как коммент превратился в ответ)

Comment: Да @insolor, кто-то преобразовал Ваш комментарий в ответ, а мой комментарий нет. Попробую перенести его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно не &, а &&.

**UPD.** А на самом деле много однотипных условий, которые на самом деле не нужны.
Делаем проще:

- Проверяем на ничью (usr==bot). Если ничья, то вывод и return.
- Проверяем на то что оба >21. Видимо тоже ничья? и return. (если это действительно должна быть ничья, то можно совместить с первым условием)
- Проверяем на однозначный выигрыш игрока (usr==21). Если выиграл - вывод и return
- Проверяем на однозначный выигрыш бота. Опять же вывод и return
- Проверяем usr > 21. Если да, то бот выиграл (и return)
- Проверяем bot > 21. Если да, то пользователь выиграл (ну вы поняли)
- Проверяем usr>bot. Если больше - вывод что выиграл пользователь, иначе - что выиграл бот.
- ну и return

В первоначальном коде не учтено условие когда оба >21.

Получилось 7 простых условий против 8 сложных

Comment: @insolor, я восхищен ! Вот, получилось (вообще я восхищен тем, что Вы прочли эту программу).

Comment: @avp, я сначала не прочитал, а окинул взглядом. Взгляд сразу же зацепился за одинарные & )